# AmCharts - Interactive buttons in Tooltip

Tags: html, events, tooltip, amcharts, amcharts4

The tooltip displays details about the marker (image) when the cursor hovers on the marker. I want to place buttons inside the tooltip which can have different effects on that map. But I don't understand how to add event listeners for the 'onclick' event of the button.

```
marker.tooltipHTML =  '<center><button onclick=\'alert("hello")\'> button </button></center>';
//marker is an object of MapImage
```

Only alert() function seems to be working. 
How can I add a function to handle the 'onclick' of this button (present in the tooltip)?

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work. I also tried defining the function f1() in a <script></script> tag and then calling it onclick = 'f1()'. This didn't work either. But thanks for helping out. Any other ideas please?

Comment: Try to have a look at the W3 example: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onclick